System is not resuming from suspend mode in Ubuntu
I'm encountering an issue with my laptop when it resumes from suspend mode. Whenever my system became idle and suspended, I could wake it by pressing a key. But now, instead of returning to the login page or resuming, the screen keeps displaying the following log and system messages:
[25757.114991] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
[25757.177850] printk: Suspending consoles(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[25757.227624] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[25757.227656] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[25757.287576] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[25757.287581] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[25757.288008] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[25757.288009] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[25757.288010] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[25757.288063] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[25757.288758] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[25757.291152] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[25757.293577] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[25757.295338] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[25757.295356] ACPI: EC: EC started
[25757.295356] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[25757.295950] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[25757.295990] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[25757.296457] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[25757.297030] CPU2 is up
[25757.297031] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[25757.297593] CPU3 is up
[25757.298837] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[25757.318903] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[25757.348253] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPI PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[25757.348354] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: Intel SPI PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[25757.348439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.6: Intel SPI PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[25758.108732] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Enabling HDA controller
[25758.108871] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[25758.148661] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[25758.148709] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[25758.326298] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[25758.478514] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[25759.002852] wl_hdp 0000:16:00.0: b63ab78e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d15b627f004: bound:000:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
[25759.011821] PM: intel_pmc_core: 
[25759.044583] Restarting tasks ... done.
[25759.048583] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[25759.049598] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[25759.053643] PM: suspend exit
[25759.061654] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[25759.084172] sata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[25759.085642] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[25759.085869] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[25760.266975] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133

(continues...)


Also, I checked:
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state  Status   Sysfs node
PS2K     S3 *enabled   pnp:00:04
        *disabled  serio:serio0
PS2M     S3 *disabled  pnp:00:05
XHC  S3 *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDAS     S4 *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
RP01     S4 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX     S4 *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
RP02     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP03     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP04     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP05     S4 *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX     S4 *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
RP06     S5 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.5
PXSX     S5 *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP07     S5 *disabled
PXSX     S5 *disabled
RP08     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP09     S4 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP10     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP11     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP12     S4 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.3
PXSX     S4 *disabled  pci:0000:05:00.0
RP13     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP14     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP15     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP16     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP17     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP18     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP19     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP20     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP21     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP22     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP23     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled
RP24     S4 *disabled
PXSX     S4 *disabled

The issue reproduces when I use the panel's suspend button or close the laptop's lid or with the command systemctl suspend.
What is causing it? How do we resolve this problem?

Update:
After finding no solution, I disabled the automatic suspend and continued using it that way. However, today I noticed that the issue seems to have been resolved, although I don't know how. The suspend feature is now working properly—I can suspend the laptop via the panel's suspend button, by closing the lid, or by using the systemctl suspend command.
